# Hooking domain to home server (WinServer2008) with specific port

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008, domain

Alright, I'm asking two things here.

First of all, if i purchase a domain let's say myhomeserver.com, am I able to make the default port go through a different port instead of the default port 80? (that is without having to do myhomeserver.com:5000 for example). Also this should be without blocking other ports (so no stealth forwarding to myhomeserver.com:5000 i think)

Secondly, How could I go about hooking a domain to a windows 2008 server? I've seen it on linux but no clue how to do it on windows if it's even possible.

I know I'm asking a lot here, just some tips are appereciated. Also, yes I know, using a home server is horrible for security and preformance and whatnot, I understand this already, thanks ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i purchase a domain let's say myhomeserver.com, am I able to make the default port go through a different port instead of the default port 80?

You can use port-forwarding in a router to change the port number on the fly.

> Secondly, How could I go about hooking a domain to a windows 2008 server?

You create an A record in your DNS management web-page/app/config-file for your domain name that points to the externally-visible IP-address of your server (usually your NAT router's external IP-address)

I'm assuming you mean domain in the sense of DNS not in the sense of Windows network server authentication.

Comment: using port forwarding in my router still wouldn't help. I'd have to connect to the port externally somehow, my provider blocks port 80, that's the problem

Comment: If your provider blocks port 80, then people will have to access your website like `http://example.com:82`, where `82` is the port you chose to use. There's no real way around that.

Comment: If your provider blocks port 80, then running a webserver probably breaks the terms of the contract you signed up for.